# Import sql data in chunks

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-workbench

I have a large size of sql file. I have to import data but when i import only 10-20 records then inserting data in database correctly but when i tried with whole file then having no data in database. May be there is some data issue So I want to insert data in chunks but could not find any right solutions. Is their any another possible solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: .SQL file in general is text file with a bunch of SQL queries. You may divide it (correctly! try do not break the query) to a lot of files and execute each of them separately (correct execution order is strongly recommended).

Answer (score 1):

As explain Henning Koch in [this card](https://makandracards.com/makandra/595-dumping-and-importing-from-to-mysql-in-an-utf-8-safe-way) the best way to import a dump safely is

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8mb4 database
mysql> SET names 'utf8'
mysql> SOURCE utf8.dump
```

And as Henning says

> Note that when your MySQL server is not set to UTF-8 you need to do mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 (!) to get a correctly encoded dump. In that case you will also need to remove the SET NAMES='latin1' comment at the top of the dump, so the target machine won't change its UTF-8 charset when sourcing.

Is important check the server configuration because you can get corrupted data if the charsets no match. In this [post](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) Mathias explain how to get full support for unicode on mysql. The important part in this post for you is the way to check the server configuration

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You must use the right charsets for you case. Check too if you target server was configured properly.

If you need modify the server configuration go to /etc/my.cnf, or if you use windows go to the server installation directory (ex. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6) and locate the my.ini file. If the file not exists copy my-default.ini into my.ini

By Mathias

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```